# "Authentication Error" after suspend

Tags: suspend

I'm having some trouble with my lock screen. Basically, if my laptop goes idle and the machine sleeps, when I wake it up by pressing a key or moving the trackpad, I just get the purple splash screen and no password box. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> my way into another TTY, I get a bunch of error messages: `Systemd-journald[312]: Failed to write entry. ignoring read only file system .` (Like a whole screen full of them). This only started when I updated to 21.04. Suspending by closing the laptop lid causes no problems at all.

This is using ubuntu with regolith. When I switch from regolith to standard ubuntu at the log in menu, waking up from suspend now I get a log in prompt, but it says "Authentication error" below the password box before I've even type anything, and I literally can't type anything in the box...

Further possibly relevant information: the laptop is a system76 lemur pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System76 support suggested I add `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line of `/etc/default/grub` and this seems to have solved the problem.